# How to Manage multiple Menus with Different Settings using mmenu

Tags: jquery, css, mmenu

I have a site with mmenu 2.2.3 installed.  The menus are set to open with a click.  You can see them in action here:

http://thedigitalcomic.com

It is not properly functioning on mobile and I want to upgrade it to mmenu 3.3.1, but it appears the syntax in this new version is dramatically different than the old.  Here is my custom-script.js file:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
   $('#show-menu').click(function(){
     $('div#responsive-menu').slideToggle('slow');
   });
    $('#hide-menu').click(function(){
     $('div#responsive-menu').slideToggle();
   });
 });


jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $(function() {
      $("#menu").mmenu({
});
      $("#menu-book").mmenu({
        position: "right"
});
      $("#menu-user").mmenu({
        position: "right"
});
});
});
```

Eventually, what I really want to do is implement the widescreen option for the right side menus and make the left side menu an iconbar style with a click to fully open.  But for now, I'm just trying to get oriented.

Can someone help me translate this older syntax of mmenu to the modern 3.3.1 version?  As it is, when I try to load in the current .js and .css files, my menus are all hosed up.

Thanks!
Rob

Answer (score 0):

As of version 3.2.0 the plugin has an option "isMenu" which determines whether or not to add menu-specific styling.
If this option is omitted, the plugin tries to automatically detect if it is a menu or not. The logic behind this is:

Is there only one childnode in the NAV and is that childnode an UL

So, basically, I think you can update to the latest version and add the isMenu-option to your js:

```
$("#menu-user").mmenu({
    position: "right",
    isMenu: true
});
```